# Accessing belongs_to association data in Sunspot results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, belongs-to, sunspot-rails

I'm working on getting my head around Sunspot and am having trouble accessing data from an associated model in Sunspot search results.

I have a Room model with fields: id, room_name, capacity, location_id. It looks like this:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to  :location

  searchable do
    text :room_name
  end

end
```

And a Location model with fields: id, location_name. It looks like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :rooms

end
```

I have a Search Controller that looks like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def later
    @search = Sunspot.search(Room)
    @results = @search.results
  end

end
```

And I'm trying to render a view that looks like this:

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <%= result.room_name %>  
  <%= result.capacity %>
  <%= result.location.location_name %> 
<% end %>
```

However I get the following error when I visit /search/later

```
NoMethodError in Search#later
Showing ./app/views/search/later.html.erb where line #4 raised:
undefined method `locations' for #<Room id: 1, room_name: "Room 1", capacity: 6, location_id: 1>
```

Without line 4 this works perfectly, the problem seems to be with where I'm reaching out to the Location model.

My understanding was that the `@results` variable should be a valid ActiveRecord object and would allow me to access data from the associated model, in this case Location?

Answer (score 0):

So with Rubyist's answer it works. However, it didn't work until I un-nested the Rooms resource in routes.rb.

I don't understand why the nested route was causing a problem though.

Comment: it wouldnt - it would have been unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with anything you're doing in terms of Sunspot and Solr.

Your error in your view is because you are calling `locations` on a Room object, when it should be `location` (as a Room belongs to a Location).

The error about `undefined method location_name for nil` is because the Room instance you are trying to index doesn't have an associated Location (ie. @room.location is nil). You can either put the indexing in a conditional (eg. `location.location_name if location.present?` or use something like `try` (eg. `location.try(:location_name)`).